# How to select PIVOT for this table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Id          Code                 Value
----------- -------------------- -----------
1           A                    100
2           B                    100
3           C                    220
4           A                    150
5           C                    300
6           D                    120
7           E                    120
```

And this is my expectation:

```
Code1       Value1      Code2       Value2      Code3       Value3
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A           100         B           100         C           220
A           150         C           300         D           120
E           120
```

Should I use PIVOT to this case (and how to do this) or normal select query?

Comment: I don't see any logic behind your expected result. Explain.

Comment: The logic in this case is take each row (one by one) to Code1 Value1 then Code2 Value2 then Code3 Value3 and go back to Code1 Value1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't with pivot either, but in case you need to group the items into groups of 3 ordered by ID and the ID has gaps, like sometimes happen, this should do it:

```
select
  ROW,
  max(case when COL = 0 then Code end) as Code1,
  max(case when COL = 0 then Value end) as Value1,
  max(case when COL = 1 then Code end) as Code2,
  max(case when COL = 1 then Value end) as Value2,
  max(case when COL = 2 then Code end) as Code3,
  max(case when COL = 2 then Value end) as Value3 
FROM (
  select
    (row_number() over (order by ID)-1) % 3 as COL,
    (row_number() over (order by ID)-1) / 3 as ROW,
    Code,
    Value
  from
    data
) X
group by ROW
```

This calculates row and column numbers based on row_number that increases over ID, and then uses group by to split the results into groups of 3.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d991/2)

Comment: Woah, I didn't know about SQL Fiddle. That's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `PIVOT` is not usefull here.

```
SELECT  t1.code as code1, t1.value as value1,
        t2.code as code2, t2.value as value2, 
        t3.code as code3, t3.value as value3 
FROM tab as t1
    left join tab as t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id - 1
    left join  tab as t3
        ON t2.id = t3.id - 1
where ((t1.id-1) % 3) = 0
```